# pyspark Loading multiple partitioned files in a single load

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, orc, partitioned-view

I am trying to load multiple files in a single load. They are all partitioned files 
When I tried it with 1 file it works, but when I listed down 24 files, it gives me this error and I could not find any documentation of the limitation and a workaround aside from doing the union after the load. 
Is there any alternatives?

CODE Below to re-create the problem:

```py
basepath = '/file/' 
paths = ['/file/df201601.orc', '/file/df201602.orc', '/file/df201603.orc',  
         '/file/df201604.orc', '/file/df201605.orc', '/file/df201606.orc',  
         '/file/df201604.orc', '/file/df201605.orc', '/file/df201606.orc',  
         '/file/df201604.orc', '/file/df201605.orc', '/file/df201606.orc',  
         '/file/df201604.orc', '/file/df201605.orc', '/file/df201606.orc',  
         '/file/df201604.orc', '/file/df201605.orc', '/file/df201606.orc',  
         '/file/df201604.orc', '/file/df201605.orc', '/file/df201606.orc',  
         '/file/df201604.orc', '/file/df201605.orc', '/file/df201606.orc', ]   

df = sqlContext.read.format('orc') \
               options(header='true',inferschema='true',basePath=basePath)\
               .load(*paths)
```

ERROR RECEIVED :

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-43-7fb8fade5e19> in <module>()

---> 37 df = sqlContext.read.format('orc')                .options(header='true', inferschema='true',basePath=basePath)                .load(*paths)
     38 

TypeError: load() takes at most 4 arguments (24 given)
```

Answer (score 5):

As explained in [the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=load#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.load), to read multiple files, you should pass a `list`:

> **path** – optional string or a list of string for file-system backed data sources.

So in your case:

```
(sqlContext.read
    .format('orc') 
    .options(basePath=basePath)
    .load(path=paths))
```

Argument unpacking  (`*`) would makes sense only if `load` was defined with variadic arguments, form example:

```
def load(this, *paths):
    ...
```